# How can I assert facts about all List members in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

I'd like to assert facts about all members of a List in prolog, and have any resulting unification retained.  As an example, I'd like to assert that each list member is equal to five, but none of the below constructs does this:

```
?- L=[X,Y,Z], forall(member(E,L), E=5).

L = [_h27057686,_h27057704,_h27057722]
X = _h27057686
Y = _h27057704
Z = _h27057722
yes

 ?- L=[X,Y,Z], foreach(member(E,L), E=5).

L = [_h27057686,_h27057704,_h27057722]
X = _h27057686
Y = _h27057704
Z = _h27057722
yes
```

I would like a way to pose the query such that `X=5`,`Y=5`, and `Z=5`.

Comment: `?- L=[X,Y,Z], maplist(=(5), L).`

Comment: `forall` sounds very logical. Alas, it is not.

Comment: Are you using "assert" and "facts" in the general accepted meaning of these words or in the Prolog meaning? The ambiguity is strong.

Comment: @false So I started thinking, if something is not very logical, what is it? Not very logical? So a bit logical? Or very illogical?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lot of terminology that you might be getting wrong, or I am misunderstanding you.

"Equal to" is not the same as "could unify", or "unify", but it depends how you mean it.

With SWI-Prolog, from the top level:

```
?- X == 5.
false. % the free variable X is not the integer 5

?- unifiable(X, 5, U).
U = [X=5]. % you could unify X with 5, then X will be 5

?- X = 5.
X = 5. % X unifies with 5 (and is now bound to the integer 5)
```

The comment by CapelliC already has the answer that you are most likely after: given a list of variables (either free or not), make so that each variable in the list is bound to the integer 5. This is best done by unification (the third query above). The `maplist` simply applies the unification to each element of the list.

PS. In case you are wondering how to read the `maplist(=(5), L)`:

These three are equivalent:

```
maplist(=(5), [X,Y,Z])
maplist(=, [5,5,5], [X,Y,Z])
X=5, Y=5, Z=5
```

And of course `X=5` is the same as `=(X,5)`.

Comment: Thanks, `maplist/2` is what I was looking for.  Also thanks to @CapelliC